# The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication for PBBI

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I was trying to connect my dev PBBI server through web service to validate address. Looks like I am having issue with authentication. I don't have documentation on this. If you guys have any clue on validating service what are ways I have to validate?

**Exception**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="DCGRealm"'

**Code**

```
var validateClient = new ValidateAddressClient("ValidateAddressPort");
 validateClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName ="Admin";
 validateClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "ADMIN";

 var address1 = new input_portAddress
 {
      AddressLine1 = "1825B Kramer Lane",
      AddressLine2 = "Suite 100",
      PostalCode = "78758",
      City = "Austin",
      StateProvince = "Texas"
  };
  var addresses = new input_portAddress[2];
  addresses[0] = address1;
  var options = new options {OutputCasing = OutputCasing.M};
  output_portAddress[] results =
                    validateClient.ValidateAddress(options, addresses);//Exception happening here.
```

**Configuration**

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="ValidateAddressSoapBinding" >
             <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
            </security>
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://webserviceURL:8080/soap/ValidateAddress"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ValidateAddressSoapBinding"
            contract="PBBIWebService.ValidateAddress" name="ValidateAddressPort"  />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

For config update this section `system.serviceModel > bindings > basicHttpBinding`

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="ValidateAddressSoapBinding" >
      <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
    </security>
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

On code side

```
var validateClient = new ValidateAddressClient();
validateClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Admin";
validateClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "ADMIN";
validateClient.Open();
var address1 = new input_portAddress
{
    AddressLine1 = "1825B Kramer Lane",
    AddressLine2 = "Suite 100",
    PostalCode = "78758",
    City = "Austin",
    StateProvince = "Texas"
};
var addresses = new input_portAddress[2];
addresses[0] = address1;
var options = new options { OutputCasing = OutputCasing.M };
output_portAddress[] results =
                    validateClient.ValidateAddress(options, addresses);
validateClient.Close();
```